# Database normalization to BCNF

Tags: database-normalization, bcnf, database-theory

I have some troubles with theoretical BCNF normalization task.

There is a relation `R(A, B, C, D, E, F)` with functional dependencies:

```
FD -> A
A -> E
E -> D
FB -> D
B -> A
```

**My line of argumentation:**

So let's start with finding potential keys, key have to contain `BCF`, because they are not obtainable. And it is only key, because we can obtain all attributes from this key.

Now we can remove redundant functional dependency `FB -> D`, because we have `B -> A -> E -> D`, right?

That means this is not even 2 NF, because of `B -> A`. And here comes first problem. I would have to extract `A` to separate table, but what with `A -> E` and `FD -> A`. Does it mean we have to do it at the same time? So that after first step in converting to 2NF, we have relations: {**BCF**DE, **B**A, **FD**A, **A**E}?

If I am right, it is now 2 NF, but it is not 3 NF, because of FD `E -> D` (E does not belong to key), so let's extract it to separate relation:
{BCEF, **E**D, **B**A, **FD**A, **A**E}

It is now 3 NF and... is it also BCNF? I do not see any FD that violates it. Or maybe my whole reasoning is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"And it is only key, because we can obtain all attributes from this key."* Following that logic, no relation can have more than one candidate key. That might not be what you meant, but it *is* what you said.

Comment: Find a textbook algorithm for putting a relation into BCNF given some FDs that are a cover. (It involves an algorithm for finding CKs of a relation given some FDs that are a cover.) You should be following such an algorithm in some reference you were given. (And normalization does not involve moving through successive normal forms.) (Although your assignment might be to move through them.) If you are going to use an ad hoc approach that involves decomposing to 2NF then you should have a reference for that algorithm or your own justification before you ask a question here. What is it?